# Cordova InAppBrowser and <a target="_blank"> not working

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, inappbrowser, cordova-plugins

I am using Cordova 3.4.1 on iOS with the InAppBrowser plugin version 0.4.0.

When I have an `<a href="...." target="_blank">` element, it is supposed to open in the InAppBrowser but it doesn't. Instead in replaces my app in the CordovaWebView and I have no way of getting back to the app.

if I do window.open it seems to work fine, but it isn't really feasible for me to add onclick handlers to all my links to then open them up in the InAppBrowser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be by design as per this bug...
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6747

Comment: That is actually a bug that I filed. I just forgot to close this question once the bug was closed. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 1):

To open in the InAppBrowser your link needs to be formatted like this`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://myurl.com', '_blank', 'location=no');">`.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `target="_system"` which should use the device's default browser

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52505237/1324) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Comment: What if we don't want to use _system?