# <a target=“_blank”> not working for local HTML Files in Android using cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, inappbrowser

I am using Cordova 6.4.0 on Android 5.1.1 (Lollipop)

When I have an  element, it is supposed to open in the new window of App but it doesn't. Instead of this, it replaces my app in the CordovaWebView and I have no way of getting back to the app.
I found this question in [Cordova InAppBrowser and <a target="_blank"> not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835720/cordova-inappbrowser-and-a-target-blank-not-working) this link but here url to be opened like google.com/youtube.com or any other.
But I want to simply open these local html files using href tag with target = _blank
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: did you miss `href="#"`  ? anchor tag will not work without `href="#"`

Comment: I used like this <a href="VIKAS/VIKASKOHLI.html" target="_blank">OPEN NEW PAGE</a>

Comment: better way to use http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/

Answer (score 0):

try using `target="_system"` which should use the device default browser.

[Cordova link reference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html)